проблема в том что при запуске кода я пишу боту он не реагирует и потом выключается
код ,проблема в том что при запуске кода я пишу боту он не реагирует и потом выключается
import asyncio
from aiogram import  Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import  Message


bot = Bot(token='тут был токен')
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message()
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('123')
    await message.reply('12312312')

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        asyncio.run(main())


Поправьте отступы, чтобы было именно так, как у вас в коде. Или у вас так и есть, что блок if __name__ == '__main__': внутри функции main?

в коде так и написанно

Тогда у вас тупо ничего не запускается. Блок if __name__ == '__main__': должен быть снаружи функции main, без дополнительных отступов. А то у вас запуск функции main находится в самой функции main, в итоге функция main не запускается вообще.

то есть     if name == 'main':
asyncio.run(main())
перед чем поставить

Вкратце: вложенность блоков в Python показывается с помощью отступов (от левой стороны). Сейчас в коде в вопросе блок if __name__ == '__main__': вложен в функцию, которую он должен вызывать. А должен быть не вложен, а быть с тем же уровнем отступа, что и сама функция main
